# javascript on click event is not working fine on img tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to open a link on image click using follwoing code

```
 <img src="AllScripts/SliderImages/images/1Main.png" alt="" title="" onclick="openSliderImage(id);"  onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'"  width="800px" height="300px" id="http://www.google.com" />
```

It is working fine but when generating image using c# write code using response.write code it doesn't work and goes on the follwoing link

```
http://localhost:1234/AllScripts/SliderImages/images/1Main.png
```

Follwoing code is used to write html

```
 <% {

                               Response.Write(SlidingImages);
                       }

                    %>
```

I know it pick the `image src` rather then `image id` on image click but why?
This is the javascript function

```
 function openSliderImage(id) {
            alert(id);
            window.open(id, '_blank');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ids like that to open links seem like a hack. I would just output the url to like link it has to open as a parameter to the function directly.

```
<img id="googleImg" onclick="openSliderImage('http://www.google.com');" src="AllScripts/SliderImages/images/1Main.png" alt="" title=""   onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'"  width="800px" height="300px" />
```

Your code doesn't run cause it will look for a javascript variable by the name 'id'.

Comment: post your javascript function too in the question. That will give an idea what is going on inside.

Comment: As per my experience some thing is wrong when generating hmtl because alert is not fired when click on image but it open the new tab and redirect to the other url which i have in question

Comment: Alert is not fired but open the link in new tab

Comment: Is this image inside an `<a>` tag? Check if you have other click handlers for images.

Answer (score 1):

change id (because you are refering to a javascript variable named id, you want to target the image id then use `this.id`

```
<img src="AllScripts/SliderImages/images/1Main.png" alt="" title="" onclick="openSliderImage(this.id);"  onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'"  width="800px" height="300px" id="http://www.google.com" />
```

I would also say you could remove onmouseover and set it with CSS (if with IE7+) img:hover (or set a cssClass so not all your images will be targeted).

Comment: @user1387147 works for me: http://jsbin.com/ebimaf/1/ is the markup valid, so you dont have an <a>-element around the image or something?

Comment: @user1387147 without the markup that actually show the problem it will be hard to give a proper answer.